# javadoc "@author" not showing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, author

Whenever I type in "Printing" and hit CTRL Q in intelliJ I can only see the "Summary" and I cant see "Bob" . . . what am I doing wrong?

```
package printing;
 /**
 * @author Bob
 * <b>Summary</b>
 */
public class Printer {
//stuff
}
```

***Note: I am just learning how to use the "javadoc" so I would appreciate an explanation.

EDIT: I cant even see "Summary" unless I take out the "@author"

Comment: I think those tags will only really be parsed if you export/generate the javadoc. In Eclipse, there is a way to Right Click your project, then export javadoc (it autogens the html and stuff). I'm sure IntelliJ has something similar. The normal summary should be present in your IDE if you create a new instance of the class and hover over it (popup tooltip usually).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a problem/feature of IntelliJ. Eclipse shows whole javadoc including `@author`. Other possible problem is a presence of `<b>Summary</b>` right after `@author`.

So, try to remove the summary and see what happens. Try also to really generate javadoc, e.g. run `javadoc` utility from command line and see what happens. I am sure that in this case `Bob` will appear. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this behavior and have raised an issue to track this : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114499

Here is the bit of code I used:

```
package printing;

/**
 * @author Simba
 * @version 1
 * @see java.util.Arrays
 * @since 1
 */
public class Printer {
}
```

And the resulting documentation:

[image]

---

However, if you try to generate the javadoc via `Tools -> Generate JavaDoc` with the following settings :

[image]

then, the resulting generated javadoc does show the author tag:

[image]

therefore proving that the javadoc itself is sound and that it is IntelliJ that does not display it.

Answer (score 1):

When `javadoc` is used from the console, you can add the `-author` and `-version` options to the call like this (*`-d` sets the output directory*):

```
javadoc src/main/java/com/*.java -d src/docs/javadocs/ -author -version
```

Author and version are displayed using those settings.

---

The `javadoc` help (by just typing `javadoc`) shows the following - as [AlexR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478399/alexr) already mentioned - (shortened):

```
...
Provided by Standard doclet:
  -d <directory>                   Destination directory for output files
  -use                             Create class and package usage pages
  -version                         Include @version paragraphs
  -author                          Include @author paragraphs
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do in command line you can use this:

```
javadoc -d javadoc -author -version  YourClass.java
```

Change the name of the .java to your class name.
Is necessary add -author if you want to show the author tag and the same with the version -version

Remember, the -d argument is used to define the folder and depend of your actual path, so if you are in C:\Users\joselito your javadoc folder has to be in C:\Users\joselito\javadoc

Answer (score 0):

When you click on generate Javadoc then you will find some options .

1. Go to below the  output directory .
2. Tick the author option .

// this is for intellij Idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).